# Cloudfront is extremely slow, auto compression is already enabled

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have cloudfront sourcing from s3 bucket. However, the load speed is many times slower than s3

The example url is [here](http://d1v2z5eq4my3py.cloudfront.net/GoQuoEngine/Themes/Malindo/Styles/malindo.bundle.css). It's merely 500KB but taking over 40 seconds to load.

I already have `Compress Objects Automatically` enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I just have to use all edge locations in Cloudfront settings.